# Downloading xcode 4 - will i be able to stick with iOS4.2 simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I want my iOS simulator to stay at 4.2, but i do want to upgrade to XCode 4 also. Would i be able to upgrade to XCode 4 and stay at iOS4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode 4 offers multiple versions of the simulator to test in. You can choose 4.1, 4.2, or 4.3 for the iPhone simulator, and 4.2 or 4.3 for the iPad.

Comment: (My version of Xcode 4 lets me simulate an iPad all the way back to 3.2.)

Comment: Note that a fresh install of XCode4 only offers a sim for the latest iOS.  When you connect devices with older versions of iOS it asks to collect data for that version, then at that point you have the sim available for that version.

Comment: there are additional iOS version packages included with every Xcode distribution that will allow you to install the specific version you want (without requiring a device)

Comment: where can i get that " additional iOS version packages". I need iOS4.2 on Xcode 4.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want your sim to stay at 4.2. It doesn't offer you anything. If you think you can use it for compatibility testing, you'd be sorely mistaken. Many things don't work right in the sim, and certainly behaviours are different in some cases. It is no suitable substitute for having a device with a particular firmware version on (the lowest you want to support at a minimum).

Short answer: No it will upgrade your sim. But no, that shouldn't ever be a problem.

Comment: It's still useful to make sure you aren't using API calls that are newer than a specific version.

Comment: Actually it's not. Use a device.

Comment: Or - the simulator.  Since you can run code more rapidly there.

Comment: Protip: For compatibility testing, use a device. The sim is never sufficient, even if it "works for your purpose". Why? Because it's unreliable. It doesn't act like a device does in many respects.